# Table row and column number in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I get the row and column number of the clicked table cell using jQuery, i.e.,

```
$("td").onClick(function(event){
   var row = ...
   var col = ...
});
```

Answer (score 227, accepted):

You can use the [Core/index](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index) function in a given context, for example you can check the index of the TD in it's parent TR to get the column number, and you can check the TR index on the Table, to get the row number:

```
$('td').click(function(){
  var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
  var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
  alert('Row: ' + row + ', Column: ' + col);
});
```

Check a running example [here](http://jsbin.com/eyeyu/edit).

Comment: Why does it fail on column spans @grom?

Comment: @Forkrul Assail, @CMS It's fail with `ROWSPAN's` http://jsbin.com/eyeyu/1099/edit#preview Click on cell with text _"12"_. Column index must be **4**

Comment: I have some datas in the variable "data".....is it possible to append this "data" into the table with this col and row value

Comment: ROWSPAN & COLSPAN work around: This makes the click work when SPAN is used  http://jsbin.com/eyeyu/1307/edit

Comment: `var row = $(this).closest('tr').index()`

Answer (score 124):

```
$('td').click(function() {
    var myCol = $(this).index();
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var myRow = $tr.index();
});
```

Answer (score 36):

Get COLUMN INDEX on click:

```
$(this).closest("td").index();
```

Get ROW INDEX on click:

```
$(this).closest("tr").index();
```

Answer (score 22):

Off the top of my head, one way would be to grab all previous elements and count them.

```
$('td').click(function(){ 
    var colIndex = $(this).prevAll().length;
    var rowIndex = $(this).parent('tr').prevAll().length;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Can you output that data in the cells as you are creating the table?

so your table would look like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td data-row='1' data-column='1'>value</td>
      <td data-row='1' data-column='2'>value</td>
      <td data-row='1' data-column='3'>value</td></tr>

  <tbody>
</table>
```

then it would be a simple matter

```
$("td").click(function(event) {
   var row = $(this).attr("data-row");
   var col = $(this).attr("data-col");
}
```

Comment: Which html spec do those attributes comply with?  I can't seem to find them.

Comment: HTML spec 5, which allows for custom attributes starting with the prefix 'data-'.

Comment: even though they aren't in spec it won't break older browsers < HTML5

Comment: You can access "data" fields just by calling: $(this).data('row');

Answer (score 0):

its better to bind a click handler to the entire table and then use event.target to get the clicked TD. Thats all i can add to this as its 1:20am

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: thanks, I will consider revising this answer in another 10 years