# HTML table, clicked row's number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Is there any way to find out row number where I recently clicked, in HTML table? 
I need this behavior to find out  whether use clicked on top and bottom of the currently selected row.

I suppose the algorithm will be:

1. select one row
2. select another row in same table
3. find out if the row selected at (2) has higher or lower index than row selected at  (1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, I'll give you a jQuery answer. You can get the index of the clicked row using jQuery's [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
   console.log($(this).index()); 
});
```

Inside the click event handler, you would be able to use the `index` method again to get the index of the currently selected row and compare them or do whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can take a look at this question, which is somewhat similar: [table row and columns number in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/788225/508702). Of course, I can give you a hint:

```
var rowIndex = $("#myrow").index();
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer because versions of IE don't understand some index operations; and because a reader might find it convenient to use pure JS rather than jQuery in this case:

Each <tr> is a children[children_index] of <tbody>. You can look in the DOM to find it and its zero-based index.