# onRowSelect: how to get cell index

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I've telerik grid.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            //columns & bound
        })
        .ClientEvents(e=> e.OnRowSelect("OnRowSelect"))
```

By clicking on the row, I need to know the cellindex (the one clicked on).
I have the function:

`function onRowSelect(e){}`

How do I extract it from there?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve the column index via the RowSelect event.

I would suggest you to attach your own delegate event like this once the Grid is initialized (via the OnLoad event):

```
function onGridLoad(){
    $(this).data().tGrid.$tbody.on('click','td',function(e){
        alert('COLUMN INDEX: '+$(this).index())
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on this question, credit to [Table row and column number in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788225/table-row-and-column-number-in-jquery).

Try this the following:

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function OnDataBound() {
        // #Grid needs to match the name of the grid in View's markup.
        $('#Grid table td').click(function () { 
            var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
            var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
            alert('Row: ' + row + ', Column: ' + col);
        });


        //As a side note, you can get at the contents of the row selected with 
        //something along these lines: 
        //(this will not work unless you substitute the "EmployeeId" id with a valid one from your model.
        $('#Grid table tr').dblclick(function () {
            alert($(this).find("span[id=EmployeeId]")[0].innerText);  //EmployeeId is just a column name used for example purposes.
        });
    }



</script>
```

Your grid markup:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        //columns & bound
    })
    .ClientEvents(e=> e.OnDataBound("OnDataBound"))  // This changed to a OnDataBound event.
```

Comment: @Refael - Did you implement the functionality that you were looking for?