# Get row.name of R Shiny tableOutput on hover

Tags: r, shiny, xtable

I would like to build a reactive input for R shiny that returns the `row.name` of a table row on hover.

In R Shiny, the table is made with `renderTable` and output through `tableOutput`.

This should work similar to the already built clickID and hoverID for plotOutput (for click & hover respectively).

I don't quite understand the JavaScript or jQuery well enough yet to follow these instructions and build it myself:

http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#building-inputs

Thank you!

---

**Update:**

This is the jQuery I have so far:

```
$(document).on('hover', '.table-hover tr', function(){
        var el = $(this);
        $(this).closest("tr").index();
}); 

var selectRowBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();
$.extend(selectRowBinding, {
        find: function(scope) {
        return $(scope).find(".table-hover");
        },
        getValue: function(el){
        return $(el).closest("tr").index();
        },
        setValue: function(el, value) {
        },
        subscribe: function(el, callback) {
        $(el).on("change.selectRowBinding", function(e) {
        callback();
        });
        },
        unsubscribe: function(el) {
        $(el).off(".selectRowBinding");
        }
});
Shiny.inputBindings.register(selectRowBinding);
```

but `input$selectRowBinding` is still returning NULL.
I'm quite sure I have *not* properly defined the bindings.

I've been working off of these 2 resources:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/selectablerows/shiny-discuss/ZaYYmFLHA6U/-cL62wQp0HUJ

and

[Shiny R application that allows users to modify data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263627/shiny-r-application-that-allows-users-to-modify-data)

Comment: This question is still open if anyone would like to take a shot at it!