# Strange value coming from table cell when added to a variable

Tags: jquery, variables, each, console.log

Ok, so I am fairly new at using jquery (I have been using plugins for years) and I simply cant figure out what is going on.

I have a table (a multiplication grid based on two user entered numbers).  The top row heading and the far left column are being generated sequentially.  So far so good.

Now, I am trying to calculate the values of the grid so x2 * y2 = grid value. 
I am planning to process 1 row at a time (as my maths brain wont allow me to work out a formula for the entire grid).  I pull the value of x row heading like this:

```
var yHead = $('.y-head.y2').text();
var xHead = $('.x-head.x2').text();
console.log(xHead);
console.log(yHead);
```

Fine, I get what I want (well I get the correct number 22 times as it is in a jquery each loop  .  So I get it 22 times).  **But** the y column heading I get the strange value 70 and the value I want. (again 22 times each due to the loop).

1) Why am I getting 22 and not 11 iteration of the each loop? 
2) where the hell is 70 coming from in the console log?

Literally loosing hair over this one...
I have tried .text(), .html(), .val()

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentieo/MBBnY/)
- the line I am working on is in red, the js is on line 22 that produces to 70

Comment: Wait.. so you're trying to do a times table, basically? is that the goal?

Comment: Yep, that is the goal.

Answer (score 0):

My first suspicion seem to be true:
At one point, `$y2` is technically a string (confirmed this while debugging).

If you replace

```
$(this).html($x2 + i);
//and
$(this).html($y2 + i);
```

with

```
$(this).html(parseInt($x2) + i);
//and
$(this).html(parseInt($y2) + i);
```

It should work the way you want it to.
Because if you have a string `"7"` and append the number `0` to it, it will be `"70"`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... so you had a few problems with that...

mine:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ja7QM/3/

This is your code...

```
// the main issue you were having had to deal with the assignment of these two 
// variables... I'm still not sure where that 70 was coming from but it was
// due to the different places and ways you assigned values to $x2 and $y2 
$y2 = $("input#Y").val();
$x2 = $("input#X").val();


    // this is your headers()
    function headers() {
    // set the heading of the grid to the values 5 lower and 5 higher than input
        $('.x-head').each(function(i) {
            $(this).html($x2 + i);
        });

    // set the heading of the grid to the values 5 lower and 5 higher than input
        $('.y-head').each(function(i) {
            $(this).html($y2 + i);
        });

    }; 
    // and mine... not much different but I used text() instead. 
    // I'm not sure it matters, really... 
    function my_headers() {   
         $('.x-head').each(function(i) { $(this).text(x2 + i); }); 
         $('.y-head').each(function(i) { $(this).text(y2 + i); }); 
    };

    // your calculate... 
    function calculate() {
    // calculate grid values (column at a time)
    $('.content.x0').each( function(i){

            var yHead = $('.y-head.y2').text();
            var xHead = $('.x-head.x2').text();
            console.log(yHead);
        })

    };


// my calculate function... be warned: I am not good at selectors.  there 
// might be a better, more efficient way... this is just the first thing 
// that worked for me... sorry.
function calculate() {  

    // find all the TR's except the first one, and go through each TD
    $('table tr:gt(0) > td').each(function(){  
        if ($(this).hasClass('content')) {

            // figure out what the Y value is for the first TD of this row 
            var y = $(this).parent('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text(); 

            // found this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788225
            // to get the column number of the current TD
            var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this)); 

            // k, so now we need that X value.  find the first tr of this table 
            // and find the td in the same column as the current TD
            var x = $(this).closest('table')
                           .find('tr:eq(0)')
                           .find('td').eq(col).text();

            x = parseInt(x,10);  // for safety in numbers 
            y = parseInt(y,10);

            $(this).text((x*y).toString());  // for safety in strings...?
        }
    });   
};


// I moved this over to the CSS because it kept getting in my way.... 
$('.content.x0').css("color", "red");

//set input A to pos x2 on the grid
$("input#X").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
// set global var of x2 based on x input
  $x2 = $(this).val() - 5;
  headers();
  calculate();
}).keyup();


// set input B position y2 on the grid
$("input#Y").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
// set global var of x2 based on x input
    $y2 = $(this).val() - 5;
    headers();
    calculate();
}).keyup();

// i just made those one thing and set x and y 
// things to update  for any change...  
//set input A to pos x2 on the grid
$("input#X, input#Y").keyup(function () {  
    x2 = $("input#X").val() - 5;
    y2 = $("input#Y").val() - 5;      
    headers();
    calculate();
}).keyup();
```