# jQueryUI drag and drop cell contents from table to another table td with column index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have 2 tables with same number of columns with some spans inside each table cell. I'm using jquery Ui draggable and droppable to drag and drop spans from one table to another.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ind;
  $('#tblTrailer td span').draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    zIndex: 100,
    start: function(event, ui) {
      var foo = $(ui.helper).parent(); // should return td
      ind = foo.index();
      $(ui.helper).css({
        padding: "2.5px 5px",
        border: "1px solid #ddd",
        background: "#f2f2f2"
      });
      console.log(ind);
    }
  });
  $('#tblTrailerBooking tr td').droppable({
    accept: "#tblTrailer td span",
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).detach().css({
        top: 'auto',
        left: 'auto',
        background: '#f3f3f3'
      }).appendTo(this);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
table tr td,
table tr th {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 12.5%;
}
table td span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id="tblTrailer" class="table table-bordered mrg-0 resource-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Resources</th>
      <th>Sep 1</th>
      <th>Sep 2</th>
      <th>Sep 3</th>
      <th>Sep 4</th>
      <th>Sep 5</th>
      <th>Sep 6</th>
      <th>Sep 7</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Trailer</td>
      <td>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-001</span>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-101</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-102</span>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-202</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="trailer">TRI-003</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-004</span>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-104</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-005</span>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-105</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="trailer">TRI-006</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-007</span>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-107</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prime Movers</td>
      <td><span class="prime">PMS-001</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="prime">PMS-002</span>
        <span class="prime">PMS-102</span>
        <span class="prime">PMS-202</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="prime">PMS-003</span>
        <span class="prime">PMS-103</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="prime">PMS-004</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="prime">PMS-005</span>
        <span class="prime">PMS-105</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="prime">PMS-006</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="prime">PMS-007</span>
        <span class="prime">PMS-107</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drivers</td>
      <td><span class="driver">DRV-001</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="driver">DRV-002</span>
        <span class="driver">DRV-102</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="driver">DRV-003</span>
        <span class="driver">DRV-103</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="driver">DRV-004</span>
        <span class="driver">DRV-104</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="driver">DRV-005</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="driver">DRV-006</span>
        <span class="driver">DRV-106</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="driver">DRV-007</span>
        <span class="driver">DRV-107</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<table id="tblTrailerBooking" class="table table-bordered mrg-0 resource-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Booking No.</th>
      <th>Sep 1</th>
      <th>Sep 2</th>
      <th>Sep 3</th>
      <th>Sep 4</th>
      <th>Sep 5</th>
      <th>Sep 6</th>
      <th>Sep 7</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>B0001</td>
      <td>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-201</span>
        <span class="prime">PMS-101</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-002</span>
        <span class="prime">PMS-302</span>
        <span class="driver">DRV-102</span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="prime">PMS-304</span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="driver">DRV-006</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="trailer">TRI-007</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B0002</td>
      <td>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-201</span>
        <span class="prime">PMS-101</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-002</span>
        <span class="prime">PMS-302</span>
        <span class="driver">DRV-102</span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="prime">PMS-304</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="driver">DRV-005</span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="trailer">TRI-007</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B0003</td>
      <td>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-201</span>
        <span>PMS-101</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="trailer">TRI-002</span>
        <span class="prime">PMS-302</span>
        <span class="trailer">DRV-102</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="driver">PMS-303</span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="driver">DRV-006</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="trailer">TRI-007</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to insert the spans to the respective columns of second table. And second table should not allow more than 3 spans in a cell one each from each rows of first table. Tried the solution provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/788292/1201322 with no luck.

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/Le6jdd8c/ .

---

Edit: I might not explained it clearly.

[image: Screenshot of the table structure]

In first table, you can see 3 rows; whereas second one has booking numbers. For each day each booking number should need to have each row content from first table. For Ex: for B001, we can add a driver for sep 1, but we can't for sep 2 as sep 2 all fulfilled. For sep 3, we have to add all three (a truck, a prime mover, and a driver from sep 3 of first table. We should not drop from any other day.

I Hope now I'm clear.

Comment: If only respective cells can be dragged and dropped how can one drop 3 spans in one cell? Please clarify the same...

Comment: I'm not dragging the cell or `td`. `span`s inside `td`.

Comment: yes for eg: u ar dragging span inside 2nd row first column it could only go to the 2nd row first column of second table, right?

Comment: @Nouphal.M I'm sorry. I might not explained the question clearly. Please see my edit. the first table has full of data. We have to assign a truck, a prime mover and a driver for a date to a specific date for specific Booking no.

Comment: still i don't understand it. It would be better if you could edit your whole question and explain what you are trying to achieve. As the reader is completely unaware of your system.

Comment: @Nouphal.M sorry to bother you. Please see my updated edit. Hope now things are clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99020/discussion-between-ravimallya-and-nouphal-m).

Comment: Have updated my answer check it.. Hope this is what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I clearly don't understand your question, but from assuming that you want to restrict the drop based on the cell index, try this solution

```
 $('#tblTrailerBooking tr td').droppable({
      accept: "#tblTrailer td span",
      activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
      drop: function(ev, ui) {
        var foo = $(ev.target); // should return td
        var spanCount  = foo.find('span').length;
        var myColInd = foo.index();
        var myRowInd = foo.parent().index();
        if(myColInd!= colIndex || rowIndex != myRowInd || spanCount > 3) {
         $(ui.draggable).draggable('option','revert',true);
         return false;
        };
        $(ui.draggable).detach().css({
          top: 'auto',
          left: 'auto',
          background: '#f3f3f3'
        }).appendTo(this);
      }
    });
```

Find [JSFIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/Le6jdd8c/11/)

```
UPDATED ANSWER FOR UPDATED QUESTION 


$('#tblTrailerBooking tr td').droppable({
        accept: "#tblTrailer td span",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            var $draggable = $(ui.draggable);
          var draggableClass = $draggable.attr('class'),
          draggableClass = draggableClass.split(' ');
          var $targetTD = $(ev.target); // should return td
          var targetColInd = $targetTD.index();
      //no need to execute other codes if col index doesn't match[ supposed to match the dates]
          if(sourceColIndex != targetColInd) {
            $draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', true);
            return false;
          }
          var targetSpans =  $targetTD.find('span');
          //Check whether item is present, if present then revert, duplicate found.          
          var flag =false;
          $.each(targetSpans,function(i,v){
             if( $(this).hasClass(draggableClass[0])){
                 flag= true;
             }    
          });
          if(flag){
             //alert the user if necessary
            //alert('Duplicate '+draggableClass[0]+' found.');
            $draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', true);
            return false;
          }

         $(ui.draggable).detach().css({
              top: 'auto',
              left: 'auto',
              background: '#f3f3f3'
            }).appendTo(this);




        }
      });
```

Find Updated [JSFIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/Le6jdd8c/21/)