# Is it possible to make td elements sortable from two different table in two different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am making a UI which consists of two different `table` elements in two different `div`. Now I have a requirement which means that I can either move one `td` element form one `table` to another `td` element or they both can be sortable. Is it possible to do that? If so then what plugin or method could I use?

This is the code:

```html
<div id="cool" draggable="true">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>lunch</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="sortable list">
        <td draggable="true" style="background-color:green">monday</td>
        <td draggable="true" style="background-color:red">eng</td>
        <td draggable="true" style="background-color:blue">hindi</td>
        <td draggable="true" style="background-color:yellow">maths</td>
        <td draggable="true" style="background-color:red">eng</td>
        <td draggable="true" style="background-color:blue">hindi</td>
        <td draggable="true" style="background-color:yellow">maths</td>
        <td draggable="true" style="background-color:red">eng</td>
        <td draggable="true" style="background-color:blue">hindi</td>
        <td draggable="true" style="background-color:yellow">maths</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and the second div is

```html
<div id="fool">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td draggable="true" style="background-color:blue">english</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td draggable="true" style="background-color:yellow">hindi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td draggable="true" style="background-color:green">maths</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td draggable="true" style="background-color:white">physics</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please do some search/research before asking questions. It's not good idea to move `td`s. However, my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471786/jqueryui-drag-and-drop-cell-contents-from-table-to-another-table-td-with-column may be helpful to you. Thanks.

Comment: sorry i am new to ui development can you please tell me why 'td' can't be sorted as it is important for my visulization that they can be sorted

Comment: If you move a td, the dom tree may gets changed and design will mess up. ex: you've 5 `td`s in a table with 3 rows, and you move the second td from second row, the third td will become the second td now (in index wise also) and the at the end of row an empty space.

Comment: no actually i want  a swaping kind of function so tree design will not changed

Comment: Consider using jQuery-UI's `.sortable();` function and try to use `<ul />` elements instead of tables to do it. You can create sortable lists (yes, you can also use tables) with jQuery-UI and you can connect multiple lists as well.

Comment: actually i was trying to use jquery-ui sortable but i desperately want two td element to be sortable or swapping is also okey

Comment: here is a pure javascript solution https://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/su7Ljm1z/ . credit goes to @crl http://stackoverflow.com/users/3183756/crl

Comment: there is no plugin right i have to perform it by pure javascript ??

Comment: No. You need not to use any javascript dependencies. It's written in pure javascript. Only thing is need a javascript enabled browser.