# Jquery how to judge the td I clicked is the first row or last row,and row index and column index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/f2w9cgo0/4/).

[image]

How can I know the td(input) I clicked is the first row or last row?

And how can I know the column index of td and the row index of td I clicked?

I know I can use `$(this)`, but how to do?

```
$("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody td").click(function(){
    //$(this)
})
```

Comment: Could this be your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788225/table-row-and-column-number-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do it. `index()` returns the index of the current position of the selected element. It starts with index 0. Therefore we need to add `+1` to the result to get the correct row/column number.

```js
$(function(){
  $('td').on('click', function(){
    var columnNumber = $(this).index() + 1; // add 1 because index starts with 0
    var rowNumber  = $(this).parent('tr').index() + 1;
    
    //Check if the culculated row number is 1
    firstcolumn = (columnNumber === 1);
    firstRow = (rowNumber === 1);
    
    //Compare the clicked element with the last element using jQuery's is() function.
    lastRow = $(this).parent('tr').is(':last-child');
    lastColumn = $(this).is(':last-child');
    
    console.log('clicked on: ' + $(this).text());
    console.log('row: ' + rowNumber);
    console.log('column: ' + columnNumber);
    
    if(firstcolumn) {
      console.log('firstColumn');
    }
    if(firstRow) {
      console.log('firstRow');
    }
    if(lastRow) {
      console.log('lastRow');
    }
    if(lastColumn) {
      console.log('lastColumn');
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1A</td>
    <td>2A</td>
    <td>3A</td>
    <td>4A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1B</td>
    <td>2B</td>
    <td>3B</td>
    <td>4B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Column and row indexing is backwards

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, fixed that.

Comment: And how to judge first row or last row,use length?

Comment: @MadFrog Could use length yes, or compare the actual elements. Updated my snippet for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody td").each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
     var row = $(this).parent('tr').index(),
             column = $(this).index();
     console.log(row, column);
  });
})
```

Row and Column will start at 0 unless otherwise specified.

Comment: no need to wrap this in an `each`. Just adding redundant code since `$(selector).method()` runs internal `each`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody td").click(function(){
    var tbl_row_count = $('#table_reach_condition_appoint>tbody>tr').length;
    var col_no = parseInt($(this).index())+1;
    var row_no = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').index())+1;
    if(row_no == 1)
    {
      alert('first row');
    }
    if(row_no == tbl_row_count)
    {
      alert('last row');
    }
   alert('You clicked row no'+row_no+' col no'+col_no);    
});
```